# Searching for a Python API that allows to launch firefox

Tags: python, url, firefox

I would love to write in Python a program that can:

1. Launch firefox browser
2. Pass automatically a given URL to that browser

I have no  idea if Python does even allow this. You can just give me a hint like the name of the library that does this work (if it exists) and I will do the rest myself.

Comment: Soo.. write it? If you'd love to do it i mean :) Programming is not so much "if it can" as it is "what you can", Python can do it and I know FireFox is quite modular. `subprocess.Popen` ;)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

One option would be to launch `Firefox` using [`selenium`](http://selenium-python.readthedocs.org/) and interact with it using `WebDriver API`:

```
from selenium import webdriver

driver = webdriver.Firefox()
driver.get(url)
```

Comment: is webdriver working the same way on windwos and ubutun ?

Comment: @begueradj yup, basically, write once, use wherever you want.

Answer (score 2):

This is actually built in to the Python standard library (I've never been exactly sure why, it's a bit of a random piece of functionality).

```
import webbrowser
webbrowser.open(my_url)
```

Comment: What webbrowser does it open? The OP asks for firefox explicitly, although it may not be relevant.

Comment: Yes, I would love what brower does webbrowser open by default

Answer (score 0):

Combine [this other answer in stackoverflow](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/89228/calling-an-external-command-in-python) with [this from mozilla's forum](https://support.mozilla.org/en-US/questions/973669) and you get:

```
from subprocess import call
call(["firefox", "http://your_url"])
```

Comment: I think this needs firefox to be run first

Comment: @begueradj Why you say so? I can't find that in mozilla documentation. I don't have firefox installed in this machine to test it.